# Functions Study Guide Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

I just have a quick question because I couldn't find the answer to this question anywhere in my textbook or any formula, and I finished everything else I was supposed to.

If 
$$f(x) = \frac{x}{3x-1},$$ 
then 
$$\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = ?$$

Comment: You need to find $f(a)$ using $f(x)=\frac{x}{3x-1}$ and just replace $f(x)$ and $f(a)$ and then simplify.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1147847/evaluate-the-difference-quotient-fx-fa-x-a-for-the-given-function something similar here

Comment: Yeah, I'm still a little confused I'm not sure how to find f(a) do I just plug in x/3x-1?

Comment: To find $f(a)$ you just replace the $x$ in $f(x)=\frac{x}{3x-1}$ with $a$

Comment: Example $f(\text{kitty})=\frac{\text{kitty}}{3(\text{kitty})-1}$

Comment: Okay, so I did that but I just end up with 3ax and -3ax canceling and i get  -x+a/x-a

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{(\color{blue}{f(x)})-(\color{green}{f(a)})}{x-a}$

$\frac{(\color{blue}{\frac{x}{3x-1}})-(\color{green}{\frac{a}{3a-1}})}{x-a}$

$\frac{\frac{\color{blue}{x}(\color{green}{3a-1})-\color{green}{a}(\color{blue}{3x-1})}{(\color{blue}{3x-1})(\color{green}{3a-1})}}{x-a}$

This can also be written as 
$\frac{\color{blue}{x}(\color{green}{3a-1})-\color{green}{a}(\color{blue}{3x-1})}{(x-a)(\color{blue}{3x-1})(\color{green}{3a-1})}$

Distribute a bit on top and somethings will zero out on top.

$\frac{({\color{blue}{x}\color{green}{3a}}-\color{blue}{x}\color{green}{1})-(\color{green}{a}\color{blue}{3x}-\color{green}{a}\color{blue}{1})}{(x-a)(\color{blue}{3x-1})(\color{green}{3a-1})}$

$\frac{(-\color{blue}{x}\color{green}{1})-(-\color{green}{a}\color{blue}{1})}{(x-a)(\color{blue}{3x-1})(\color{green}{3a-1})}$

$\frac{-x+a}{(x-a)(3x-1)(3a-1)}$

Now notice $-x+a=-(x-a)$
And see if you can continue from there.